# Change default group colors in Zeppelin visualizations

Tags: visualization, apache-zeppelin

I have a bunch of data that I'm putting into a scatter plot, but the default color ordering is "blue", "lighter blue", and then finally "orange". My data comes in two groups, with constant group names, and no mater what I do, they're always the blue and lighter blue. Which does NOT make for a good visualization.

So far, I haven't found a way to modify the color ordering, or to set specific colors for the known groups. I also haven't been able to change the colors by adding a dummy group (of one element) and playing with the ordering in the SQL statement.

Any help?

Comment: There's issue [ZEPPELIN-2633](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2633) for this, which is yet unresolved and uncommented.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround/hack for that missing Zeppelin feature.

Charting in Zeppelin is based on [nvd3](https://github.com/nvd3/nvd3) (which in turn uses the D3 library). As Zeppelin simply doesn't care about colors yet, it'll always use the nvd3 default, which is defined in the `utils.js` function [`nv.utils.defaultColor`](https://github.com/nvd3/nvd3/blob/master/src/utils.js#L109).

So, to change the color scheme, you can simply override this function. Try out the following JavaScript code in your browser's console. For available color schemes, see the [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#category10) (note, that Zeppelin still uses the old 3.x version of D3).

```
nv.utils.defaultColor = function() { 
    return nv.utils.getColor(d3.scale.category10().range());
}
```

The remaining problem is, how to permanently add this to your Zeppelin instance, which depends on your environment. It is sufficient to add the above code to the end of your `index.html`, however this involves modifying the `zeppelin-web-x.y.z.war` file.

In the end, with above code, you get something like this.

[image: Screenshot of Zeppelin chart with changed color scheme]